# JsonDecodeError while fetching response from API

Tags: python, json, api

So i am trying to get a simple response from an api, and when I try to pull a response from the api, I get an error:
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

```
import requests
import json
current = "https://covidtracking.com/api/v1/states/current"
response = requests.get(current)
print(response.status_code)
gg = json.dumps(response.json(), indent = 4)
```

the traceback is as follows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-c5319b3765a1> in <module>
----> 1 gg = json.dumps(response.json(), indent = 4)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py in json(self, **kwargs)
    895                     # used.
    896                     pass
--> 897         return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
    898 
    899     @property

~\anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    346             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    347             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 348         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    349     if cls is None:
    350         cls = JSONDecoder

~\anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    335 
    336         """
--> 337         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    338         end = _w(s, end).end()
    339         if end != len(s):

~\anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354         except StopIteration as err:
--> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
​
```

What exactly am I doing wrong here? I would also appreciate tips on making the code better or more efficient, I am still learning how to code python.

Thank you!

Comment: Go here instead: https://covidtracking.com/api/v1/states/current.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use the HTML version of the API. Instead, point your code to use the below URL.

```
import requests
import json
current = "https://covidtracking.com/api/v1/states/current.json"
response = requests.get(current)
print(response.status_code)
#get the data from the API response as JSON
covid_data = response.json()
#Since we have the data by state, loop through each state
for data in covid_data:
    #read the individual attributes from the data for each state and print / process as required.
    print(f"{data['state']}-{data['positive']}")
```

Please refer this [URL](https://covidtracking.com/api) which gives details on the API that returns JSON and the ones that return CSV.